# javascript fetch resulting in undesirable format?

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, leaflet

I don't understand what is happening here. I am trying to load data via the code below. when the 3 commented out lines are uncommented the console.log shows the result as`[]`and the rest of the code does not work even though at this point I am not even using the data that has been fetched.

If I comment out the 3 lines of code and the console.log shows `(5) [i, i, i, i, i]` and the rest of the code works as desired, which is to plot markers on a leaflet map. I am not sure what this means, and the data inside each set although numbered the same 0-4 seems formatted differently.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var groupMarkers = [];

async function getData() {
    const response = await fetch('../../Export2.log');    //These are the lines causing problems
    var data = await response.text();                     //These are the lines causing problems
    var formatedData = JSON.parse('[' + data.trim().replace(/\n/g, ',') + ']')   //These are the lines causing problems


    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).bindPopup("I am a green leaf.");
        groupMarkers.push(marker);
    }
}
getData();
setInterval(getData, 5000);
L.layerGroup(groupMarkers).addTo(map);
console.log(groupMarkers);
```

Here is the entire page for testing

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
    <title>Map Data Test</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew==" crossorigin=""></script>


    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='map'></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

// Start Map
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.5, -0.09], 7);

L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
        '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
        'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    id: 'mapbox/light-v9',
    tileSize: 512,
    zoomOffset: -1
}).addTo(map);


var groupMarkers = [];

async function getData() {
    const response = await fetch('../../Export2.log');
    var data = await response.text();
    var formatedData = JSON.parse('[' + data.trim().replace(/\n/g, ',') + ']')


    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).bindPopup("I am a green leaf.");
        groupMarkers.push(marker);
    }
}
getData();
setInterval(getData, 5000);
L.layerGroup(groupMarkers).addTo(map);
console.log(groupMarkers);
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `then` with `fetch`:

```
  var groupMarkers = [];
  var fg = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
  async function getData() {
    const response = fetch("Export.log")
    .then(response => response.text()) // or `response.json()` to get a json object
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      fg.clearLayers();
      var json = JSON.parse("[" + data.trim().replace(/\n/g, ",") + "]");
      console.log(json);
      json.forEach((latlng)=>{
        console.log(latlng)
        var marker = L.marker([latlng.Lat,latlng.Long]).bindPopup("I am a green leaf.");
        groupMarkers.push(marker);
        fg.addLayer(marker);
      });
      map.fitBounds(fg.getBounds())
    });
  }
  getData();
  setInterval(getData, 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response to my question. Unfortunately, this does not fix the problem. I have set up a code sandbox to demonstrate the issue. I have updated with the above code. Currently I have commented out the section above except for the working portion of the code. The code will produce 5 markers on the map although it looks like 1 because they all have the same coordinates. When uncommenting the lines in the problematic code the marker(s) dont show up anymore and the data changes... https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-elion-uspb3?file=/index.html

Comment: Thank you for this! The code is now working as desired.